# How can I deblur this photograph?

Tags: image-processing

I want to apply some transformations to the image below to enhance its quality. What can I do?

[image: bicycles]

Comment: `Sharpen[image,15]` helps a bit. You can use `Manipulate[Sharpen[image, h], {h, 1, 100, 1}]` to adjust the sharpness

Comment: Also `2*image - CurvatureFlowFilter[image, 50]`

Answer (score 1):

```
MinimalBy[Entropy[First[#]]&]@Flatten[
    Table[
        {
            ImageDeconvolve[
                img
                , GaussianMatrix[{10,{k1,k2}}]
                , Method->m
            ]
            ,{k1,k2,m}
        }
        , {k1, 0.2, 1.6, 0.1}
        , {k2, 0.2, 1.6, 0.1}
        , {m, {"DampedLS", "Tikhonov", "TSVD", "Wiener"}}
    ]
    , 2
]
```

[image]

[image]

If you know that the images is blurred by movement, you could try [`ImageDeconvolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDeconvolve.html) with a kernel that is a wiggly line that follows the trajectory of the movement.